# Finding the eigenfunctions and eigenvectors from a linear span?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $V$ be the linear span of the functions $1,\cos(x),\sin(x)$. Let the operator $T$
 on $V$
 be given by the rule $Ty(x)=y(x+\frac{\pi}4)$. Find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $T$ in $V$.

I know how to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for a matrix, but I do not know how to find them in this situation.

Comment: btw, in the future, do not just copy and paste question from some word or pdf. Look at the question after you posted it and see whether there is a formatting issue. You have to learn to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) on this site to type maths.

Answer (score 2):

Since $V$ operates on a finite-dimensional space, you can compute a matrix in the usual way. First, pick a basis for $V$ ($1, \sin, \cos$ should do the trick). Then, compute $T$ applied to each basis vector. Finally, find the coordinate vector for $T(1), T(\sin), T(\cos)$ in terms of the basis $1, \sin, \cos$. These will be the columns of your matrix.

Once you've done this, then the eigenvalues of $T$ will be the eigenvalues of the matrix you've computed. Moreover, the eigenvectors of the matrix will be coordinate vectors of the eigenvalues of the operator $T$.

Answer (score 0):

Some minor guide to hopefully get you started:

$$T(1)=1$$
$$T(\sin(x))= a\sin x + b \cos x$$
$$T(\cos(x)) = c\sin x + d\cos x$$

Study the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0  & a & c \\ 0 & b & d\end{bmatrix}$$

Find its eigenvectors and eigenvalues. Try to get an idea of how to construct eigenvalue and eigenvector for your original problem